# convert steam into object in mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am using a s3 connector to read the tar file and send data to java class to the unzip the tar file and put the extracted file to target folder. This process is working fine in mule3 but now we are migrating it to mule4 and here we are facing issue.

currently in mule 4 first i am creating instance of java class and adding that instance to java invoke component. Below please find the mule and java code. Please suggest or correct the code to run successfully below code.

```
    <java:new doc:name="Creating an Instance of TarExtraction" doc:id="5aa0e7ea-218c-4b46-b071-b76a2fb2a44f" class="com.int100b.TarExtraction" constructor="TarExtraction()" target="TarExtraction"/>

    <java:invoke method="onCall(java.lang.Object)" doc:name="Invoke onCall" doc:id="20c83a08-b684-4e37-bc82-bdbff5f4eed1" instance="#[vars.TarExtraction]" class="com.int100b.TarExtraction">

     <java:args ><![CDATA[#[{
     arg0: payload
    }]]]></java:args>
    </java:invoke>
```

java code:

```
            package com.int100b;
            import java.io.File;
            import java.io.FileOutputStream;
            import java.io.InputStream;
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.List;

            import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
            import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveEntry;
            import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream;
            import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
            import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
            public class TarExtraction { //implements Callable {
            @Value("/tmp/int100")
            String OUTPUT_FOLDER;
            //private static final String OUTPUT_FOLDER = "/tmp/int100";
            private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(TarExtraction.class);
            public TarExtraction() {}
            public Object onCall(Object payload) throws Exception {
            //  public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            List<String> datfileName = new ArrayList<String>();
            InputStream context = (InputStream) payload;
            //InputStream context = (InputStream) eventContext.getMessage().getPayload();
            TarArchiveInputStream tar = new TarArchiveInputStream(context);
            TarArchiveEntry te = tar.getNextTarEntry();
            while (te != null) {
            if (!te.isDirectory()) {
            String fileName = te.getName();
            if(fileName.contains("/")){
            fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
            }
            File newFile = new File(OUTPUT_FOLDER + File.separator + fileName);
            LOG.info("file unzip : " + newFile.getAbsoluteFile());
            datfileName.add(fileName);
            new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            int len;
            while ((len = tar.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            fos.close();
            }
            te = tar.getNextTarEntry();
            }
            tar.close();
            LOG.info("Tar files " + datfileName);
            return datfileName;
            }

            }
```

Error:

```
        Message : Invocation of Method 'onCall(java.lang.Object)' from Class 'com.int100b.TarExtraction' with arguments [org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider arg0] resulted in an error.

        Expected arguments are [java.lang.Object payload].

        Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException - org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider cannot be cast to java.io.InputStream
```

Comment: There are too many missing details for an answer. Share the source code of the Java method to understand what it does. Why are you using `^raw`? What does `vars.fileData` contain exactly? Do you have a Java stacktrace of the error or can you generate one? Is the cast to `java.io.InputStream` in your Java code? `TarExtraction` suggest the file is a tar file, not a CSV file. Is that correct? Edit your question to add details. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi @aled I've modified the description. Please check and let me know if any solution is there.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because your Java code is assuming the Object parameter is an InputStream, but that is an incorrect assumption in Mule 4:

```java
        InputStream context = (InputStream) payload;
```

Probably that worked in Mule 3. In general having an Object argument when it is expected it is something specific causes confusions.

Try letting Mule and the Java Module to take care of this for you:

1. Ensure you have the [latest Java Module version](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/connector/java-module) in your project.
2. Change the method signature to expect an InputStream as the argument:

```java
    public Object onCall(InputStream payload)...
```

For reference see: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/java-invoke-inputstream

If you still have problems you may need to change the file input source to non-repeatable-stream.